# Unable to view Eureka Dashboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have a simple spring boot application on which I am trying to run a Eureka server.

This is my main application file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my application property file

```
spring.application.name=netflix-eureka-naming-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Dependencies used.

```
spring boot version : 2.2.4.RELEASE
spring cloud version : Hoxton.SR1
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
```

But when I run the application and visits the localhost:8761 then I get an Whitelabel page error showing 404 NOT FOUND.

and when I changed the configuration according to this post [unable to render eureka dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069134/unable-to-render-eureka-dashboard)

then it started showing me an XML page instead of the dashbord.

Can someone help me out here ?

Comment: What does it say in the log ?

Comment: if you mean the application logs then the application started successfully without any error I can see "started eureka server" and "application started" logs

Answer (score 0):

Eureka Dashboard should be available unter http://localhost:8761/eureka/

Comment: I had already checked that URL but it shows not found also like page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue.

Just add these two properties in your application.properties file and it will work.

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path= classpath:/templates/
spring.freemarker.prefer-file-system-access= false
```

I am using spring boot version 2.2.4.RELEASE and springCloudVersion Hoxton.SR1